# Replacing multiple values in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to replace multiple values in one cell with a specific value.
An example of current excel sheet where following data is stored in one cell (e.g. A6):

`60.54296875 60.533203125 60.5458984375 60.5419921875 60.544921875 60.53515625 60.533203125 60.5224609375`

This is just a short example of the data - I'm working with thousands.

I'm looking for a code that can change all the data within the cell to:

```
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Hope I've specified the problem enough.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: so if you have 8 numbers in a cell you want it to display 100 8 times ?

Comment: If you want to overwrite the existing cell contents then you'll need programming/macro, or manually do a find and replace.

Answer (score 0):

As OP looked for Code, here is the code:

```
Sub substituteText()

' Add space at the end of cell 
    Range("A6").Value = Range("A6").Value & " "

'Replace cell value with desired text
    Range("A6").Replace What:="* ", Replacement:="100 "

'Trim to remove space at the end of cell
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim (Range("A6"))

End Sub
```

Bonus: 
The following formula will also work:

`=TRIM(REPT("100 ", LEN(A6)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A6," ",""))+1))`